# Top bar buttons text vertical alignment

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

It seems like the text on the buttons in the top bar is pushed upwards by the line on the bottom. Seems like it should not happen, since it catches my attention, even if it is a small glitch.

[image: screenshot]

Mac OS 10.13.1, Chrome 64.0.3260.2-dev

Comment: it would be better to add info like browser, its version and OS etc.. no repro in chrome latest in Mac OS Sierra

Comment: Thanks, added environment info.

Comment: Hmm.. dev edition _maybe_ a browser thing... a developer would confirm

Comment: I can repro this in Firefox 56.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: It is up by the height of the horizontal black selection bar underneath the selected tab.

Comment: Can repro in Chrome 59.0.3071.86 on Windows 7.

Comment: The issue is that the 2px `border-bottom` is defined for `-item._current`, but doesn't exist in the normal cases where `-item:not(._current)`. The rule defining it is: `.top-bar .navigation .-item._current .-link {border-bottom: 2px solid #F48024; font-weight: normal }` (color is different on meta vs. main).

Comment: Can also reproduce this in Firefox 57.0.1 (64-bit) on Debian/Linux. I think we can all conclude that this issue is *not* browser specific.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by adding the following:

```
.top-bar .navigation .-item._current .-link {
    padding: 2px 12px 0 12px;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I don't see an issue with it, seems like it puts more emphasis on the selected tab